# JavaScript templating language: ivy-markup

Tags: javascript, parsing, node.js, template, modules

This library is a markup parser which is intended to be used in node.js and browser environment. I've decided to use Jasmine for tests.

The library's name is ivy-markup. URL: https://github.com/AlexAtNet/ivy-markup

It would be great to get comments on its usability and code structure.

Main engineering ideas:

- Parser parses the rest of the stream by trying several possibilities (e.g. try to parse table, then line, then characters)
- Parser creates a tree of nodes
- Rendering is two-step: node rendering and HTML tag rendering

Significant code fragments:

parser.js

```
    // Character ranges:
    (function () {
        /**
         * Reads whitespace characters from the stream.
         */
        Parser.prototype.whitespace = function (state) {
            return state.read(this.whitespaceCharacter);
        };

        /**
         * Reads whitespace character from the stream.
         */
        Parser.prototype.whitespaceCharacter = function (state) {
            if (state.end() || !state.current(/[ \t]/)) {
                return null;
            }
            return state.fetch();
        };

        /**
         * Reads characters from the stream.
         *
         * Reads the current character and then calls the character method
         * until it returns null.
         *
         * Examples (| - state position):
         *  " |asd, qwe. [a|...] " -> {"asd, qwe. "}, " asd, qwe. |[a|...] "
         *  " |e@mail.com!" -> {"e"}, " e|@mail.com!"
         *  " e|@mail.com!" -> {"@mail.com"}, " e@mail.com|!"
         */
        Parser.prototype.characters = function (state) {
            return this.createCharacterNode(
                (this.character(state) || state.fetch() || '') +
                    (state.read(this.character) || '')
            );
        };

        /**
         * Reads character from the stream.
         *
         * Returns:
         *  1. current character when it is uppercase or lowercase letter
         *     from A-Z, digit, comma, point, or white space
         *  2. character after backslash when it is not from #1
         *  3. backslash when it is followed by the character from #1
         *  4. null when the state ends or not #1-#3.
         *
         * Examples (| - state position):
         *  a|sdf -> s, as|df
         *  a|\sdf -> \, a\|sdf
         *  a|\\sdf -> \, a\\|sdf
         *  a|\.sdf -> ., a\.|sdf
         *  asdf| -> null, asdf|
         *
         * Called from:
         *  characters
         */
        Parser.prototype.character = function (state) {
            if (state.end()) {
                return null;
            }
            if (state.current(/[a-z\d\.\, ]/i)) {
                return state.fetch();
            }
            if (state.current('\\')) {
                state.move();
                if (state.end() || state.current(/[a-z\d]/i)) {
                    return '\\';
                }
                return state.fetch();
            }
            return null;
        };
    }());
```

renderer.js

```
    Renderer.prototype.node = function (node, callback) {
        var tag = this.tag.bind(this);

        switch (node.type) {
        case 'plugin':
            this.plugins[node.plugin.name].render(node, callback);
            break;
        case 'heading':
            this.nodes(node.nodes, function (result) {
                callback(tag('h' + node.level, { id : node.id }, result));
            }.bind(this));
            break;
        case 'list':
            this.nodes(node.nodes, function (result) {
                callback(tag({
                    'unordered' : 'ul',
                    'ordered' : 'ol'
                }[node.list], result));
            });
            break;
        ...
        case 'table':
            this.nodes(node.nodes, function (result) {
                callback(tag('table', { 'class' : 'table' }, result));
            });
            break;
        case 'table-row':
            this.nodes(node.nodes, function (result) {
                callback(tag('tr', result));
            });
            break;
        ...
```

index.js

```
'use strict';

/*global module, window, require */

var noConflict, ivy;

ivy = function (markup, done) {
    (function (markup, done) {
        var parser = new this.Parser(),
            tags = new this.Tags(),
            renderer = new this.Renderer(tags);
        renderer.render(parser.parse(markup), done);
    }.call(ivy, markup, done));
};

if (('undefined' !== typeof module) && undefined !== module.exports) {
    ivy.Parser = require('./parser.js');
    ivy.Tags = require('./tags.js');
    ivy.Renderer = require('./tags.js');
    module.exports = ivy;
} else if ('undefined' !== typeof window) {
    if (undefined === window.ivy) {
        noConflict = (function (previous) {
            return function () {
                window.ivy = previous;
                return ivy;
            };
        }(window.ivy));
    } else {
        noConflict = (function (previous) {
            return function () {
                window.ivy = previous;
                return ivy;
            };
        }(window.ivy()));
    }
    ivy.noConflict = noConflict;
    ivy.Parser = window.ivy.Parser;
    ivy.Tags = window.ivy.Tags;
    ivy.Renderer = window.ivy.Renderer;
    window.ivy = ivy;
}
```

Comment: My first comment would be:  Don't make people include 4 separate script files to use your library.  Why not provide a fifth script that just includes the other 4 scripts when it runs?

Comment: Per the FAQ, your question needs to contain actual code for review here and not a link to the code. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Sorry. I've added some significant code examples and engineering ideas.

Comment: If your script is supposed to run in the browser and node per your description I'd suggest you use `this` rather than `window` in *index.js*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've stared at the code for a while;

- I assuming you wrote `whitespaceCharacter` to mimic the separation between `characters` and `character`. However, since you only refer once to `whitespaceCharacter` I would put that function inside `Parser.prototype.whitespace`.
- The massive case statement in renderer.js gives me the heebeegeebees, one missing `break` and you are on the hook for some interesting debugging. Personally, I would probably go for something like this ( because `node.type` is a string):

  ```
  var nodeTypeHandlers = {

    plugin : function(){
      this.plugins[node.plugin.name].render(node, callback);
    }, 
    heading: function(){
      this.nodes(node.nodes, function (result) {
        callback(tag('h' + node.level, { id : node.id }, result));
      }.bind(this));
    },
    table: function(){
      this.nodes(node.nodes, function (result) {
        callback(tag('table', { 'class' : 'table' }, result));
      });
    },
    table-row: function(){
      this.nodes(node.nodes, function (result) {
        callback(tag('tr', result));
      });
    },
    ...
  }
  ```

  and then simply execute `nodeTypeHandlers[node.type].call(this);`
- Other than that, the code is well commented, readable and JSHint cannot find anything.